# Importing wsdl from c#.net code to delphi doesn't generate all fields

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-7

I have D7. I have downloaded wsdlImp program:
Borland WSDLIMP Version 2.2 - $Rev: 10138 $ (which is shipped with delphi 2007) and it seems
to work with D7.

I have c# interface as follows:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService
{
  [OperationContract]
  RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request);

  [OperationContract]
  void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request);
}
[MessageContract]
public class DownloadRequest
{
  [MessageBodyMember]
  public string FileName;
}

[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
  [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
  public string FileName;

  [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
  public long Length;

  [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
  public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

  public void Dispose()
  {
    if (FileByteStream != null)
    {
      FileByteStream.Close();
      FileByteStream = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Delphi wsdl import generates:

```
unit TransferService;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

const
  IS_OPTN = $0001;
  IS_NLBL = $0004;
  IS_REF  = $0080;         

type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Borland types; however, they could also 
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:base64Binary    - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:string          - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:long            - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]

  DownloadRequest      = class;                 { "http://tempuri.org/"[Lit][GblElm] }
  RemoteFileInfo       = class;                 { "http://tempuri.org/"[Lit][GblElm] }
  FileName             = class;                 { "http://tempuri.org/"[Hdr][Alias] }
  Length               = class;                 { "http://tempuri.org/"[Hdr][Alias] }

  StreamBody      =  TByteDynArray;      { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message"[GblSmpl] }


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : DownloadRequest, global, <element>
  // Namespace : http://tempuri.org/
  // Serializtn: [xoLiteralParam]
  // Info      : Wrapper
  // ************************************************************************ //
  DownloadRequest = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FFileName: WideString;
    FFileName_Specified: boolean;
    procedure SetFileName(Index: Integer; const AWideString: WideString);
    function  FileName_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
  published
    property FileName: WideString  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read FFileName write SetFileName stored FileName_Specified;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : RemoteFileInfo, global, <element>
  // Namespace : http://tempuri.org/
  // Serializtn: [xoLiteralParam]
  // Info      : Wrapper
  // ************************************************************************ //
  RemoteFileInfo = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FFileByteStream: StreamBody;
  public
    constructor Create; override;
  published
    property FileByteStream: StreamBody  read FFileByteStream write FFileByteStream;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : FileName, alias
  // Namespace : http://tempuri.org/
  // Serializtn: [xoSimpleTypeWrapper]
  // Info      : Header
  // ************************************************************************ //
  FileName = class(TSOAPHeader)
  private
    FValue: WideString;
  published
    property Value: WideString  read FValue write FValue;
  end;



  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : Length, alias
  // Namespace : http://tempuri.org/
  // Serializtn: [xoSimpleTypeWrapper]
  // Info      : Header
  // ************************************************************************ //
  Length = class(TSOAPHeader)
  private
    FValue: Int64;
  published
    property Value: Int64  read FValue write FValue;
  end;


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : http://tempuri.org/
  // soapAction: http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/%operationName%
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // style     : document
  // binding   : BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService
  // service   : TransferService
  // port      : BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService
  // URL       : http://localhost:1875/TransferService.svc
  // ************************************************************************ //
  ITransferService = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{8D28E73C-15D9-7F1E-9D04-A024598C5EA2}']

    // Cannot unwrap: 
    //     - Input element wrapper name does not match operation's name
    // Headers: FileName:pOut, Length:pOut
    function  DownloadFile(const parameters: DownloadRequest): RemoteFileInfo; stdcall;

    // Cannot unwrap: 
    //     - Input element wrapper name does not match operation's name
    // Headers: FileName:pIn, Length:pIn
    procedure UploadFile(const parameters: RemoteFileInfo); stdcall;
  end;

function GetITransferService(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): ITransferService;


implementation
  uses SysUtils;

function GetITransferService(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): ITransferService;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://localhost:1875/TransferService.svc?wsdl';
  defURL  = 'http://localhost:1875/TransferService.svc';
  defSvc  = 'TransferService';
  defPrt  = 'BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as ITransferService);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;


constructor DownloadRequest.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FSerializationOptions := [xoLiteralParam];
end;

procedure DownloadRequest.SetFileName(Index: Integer; const AWideString: WideString);
begin
  FFileName := AWideString;
  FFileName_Specified := True;
end;

function DownloadRequest.FileName_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FFileName_Specified;
end;

constructor RemoteFileInfo.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FSerializationOptions := [xoLiteralParam];
end;

initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(ITransferService), 'http://tempuri.org/', 'utf-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(ITransferService), 'http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/%operationName%');
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(ITransferService), ioDocument);
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(ITransferService), ioLiteral);
  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(ITransferService), FileName, 'FileName', 'http://tempuri.org/');
  InvRegistry.RegisterHeaderClass(TypeInfo(ITransferService), Length, 'Length', 'http://tempuri.org/');
  InvRegistry.RegisterExternalParamName(TypeInfo(ITransferService), 'DownloadFile', 'parameters1', 'parameters');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(StreamBody), 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message', 'StreamBody');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(DownloadRequest, 'http://tempuri.org/', 'DownloadRequest');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(DownloadRequest, [xoLiteralParam]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(RemoteFileInfo, 'http://tempuri.org/', 'RemoteFileInfo');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(RemoteFileInfo, [xoLiteralParam]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(FileName, 'http://tempuri.org/', 'FileName');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(FileName, [xoSimpleTypeWrapper]);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(Length, 'http://tempuri.org/', 'Length');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterSerializeOptions(Length, [xoSimpleTypeWrapper]);

end.
```

The problem is with the code here:

```
ITransferService = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{8D28E73C-15D9-7F1E-9D04-A024598C5EA2}']

    // Cannot unwrap: 
    //     - Input element wrapper name does not match operation's name
    // Headers: FileName:pOut, Length:pOut
    function  DownloadFile(const parameters: DownloadRequest): RemoteFileInfo; stdcall;

    // Cannot unwrap: 
    //     - Input element wrapper name does not match operation's name
    // Headers: FileName:pIn, Length:pIn
    procedure UploadFile(const parameters: RemoteFileInfo); stdcall;
  end;
```

How Can i Workaround the problem? What is the reason of that unwrap error?

---

Here is the wsdl code:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" name="TransferService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:1875/TransferService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:1875/TransferService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:1875/TransferService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="DownloadRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DownloadRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="RemoteFileInfo">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RemoteFileInfo"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="RemoteFileInfo_Headers">
<wsdl:part name="FileName" element="tns:FileName"/>
<wsdl:part name="Length" element="tns:Length"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ITransferService_UploadFile_OutputMessage"/>
<wsdl:portType name="ITransferService">
<wsdl:operation name="DownloadFile">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/DownloadFile" name="DownloadRequest" message="tns:DownloadRequest"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/DownloadFileResponse" name="RemoteFileInfo" message="tns:RemoteFileInfo"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="UploadFile">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/UploadFile" name="RemoteFileInfo" message="tns:RemoteFileInfo"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/UploadFileResponse" message="tns:ITransferService_UploadFile_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" type="tns:ITransferService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="DownloadFile">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/DownloadFile" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="DownloadRequest">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="RemoteFileInfo">
<soap:header message="tns:RemoteFileInfo_Headers" part="FileName" use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:RemoteFileInfo_Headers" part="Length" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="UploadFile">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ITransferService/UploadFile" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="RemoteFileInfo">
<soap:header message="tns:RemoteFileInfo_Headers" part="FileName" use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:RemoteFileInfo_Headers" part="Length" use="literal"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="TransferService">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:1875/TransferService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: When using WDSL of the type "document/literal wrapped" one condition is: "The name of the input wrapper element must be the same as the web service operation name in WSDL" according to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-usagewsdl/index.html)
Maybe that's what's going on. Read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/ for a discussion of WSDL styles

Comment: I have added wsdl code form the service. Neither I am familiar with the soap format nor I know how to fix c# wsdl ...

Comment: Is this issue resloved?

Comment: @JanDoggen - The url is no longer valid unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `<wsdl:definitions targetNameSpace ...>` match your `<xsd:schema targetNamespace ...>`.  That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This should have read:  "Try making your <wsdl:definitions targetNamespace ...> match your <xsd:schema targetNamespace ...>

Comment: I've fixed this for you - you needed to escape your xml with backticks. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try, instead of:

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:1875/TransferService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
```

Make the XSD a local file. e.g. "c:\temp\file0.xsd"

In some cases - mostly when the http url is actually a https url, or the port is invalid - delphi will not respond well to the redirect and simply mark the functions as "Cannot unwrap".

I understand this won't help you if you are making your WSDL for others, but if you're just trying to import the WSDL to use in delphi it might help some readers.